# googlr speech client api returns empty result

Tags: c#, .net, google-speech-api

I am trying to implement speech to text using google speech client library in .net. I was trying to work on the library with a .raw file(which plays alright on media players but the google api returns empty result.

Can someone tell me if I am missing something. Here is my code

```
private string GetSpeechToText()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.Create();

            RecognitionConfig config = new RecognitionConfig()
            {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                LanguageCode = "en-US",
            };

            RecognizeResponse response = speechClient.Recognize(config,
                RecognitionAudio.FromFile(fileName));

            foreach (var responseResult in response.Results)
            {
                foreach (var alternative in responseResult.Alternatives)
                {
                    result += alternative.Transcript;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return result;
        }

        return result;
    }
```